# Как напечатать число типа numpy.float64 в фиксированном формате

Tags: python, numpy

Необходимо округлить число  `4.78221659393e-07`. Число принадлежит к типу class 'numpy.float64'. round работает как я понял со строками поэтому он тут просто выводит что типа этого `4.78221659393e-`
Как можно округлить или представить полном виде чтоб уже дальше можно было работать как со cтрокой?

Нужно убрать степень. Чтобы было не `e-07` а `0.00....478221659393`

Comment: `round()` работает с числами. К примеру:  `round(1.2345, 2) -> 1.23`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Число с фиксированной точностью](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592133/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вопрос в отображении числа в строке то его лучше не преобразовывать,
но отображать в верном формате, вот так можно:

```
а = float(1.121e-05)
s = '%.20f' %f

>>> s
>>> '0.00001121000000000000'
```