# Python вычислить сумму последовательности с заданной точностью

Tags: python, python-3.x

Попросили решить простую задачку, но я знаю php, c++, а вот с питоном не дружу.
Понял, что есть форматирование чисел format, но как использовать не ясно

вычислить сумму последовательности x/(n+ 3n^2+5) c точностью 1.e-8 для x на отрезке [1; 2.8] с шагом 0.2 Результат занести в таблицу

```
x = float(input('Введите X в интервале [1; 2.8]: '))
#eps = 1.e-8
n = 1
z = 0
while z <= 2.8:
    z += x / ((n + 3 * (n ** 2)) + 5)
    n += 0.2
    print(z)
print("сумма ряда: ", z)
```

Comment: в тексте вопроса явно упомяните диапазон и значения для `n`. Из *"для x на отрезке [1; 2.8] с шагом 0.2"* не очевидно, какие значения `n` должно принимать (может `n` должно изменяться от `0` до бесконечности?). Не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи. `z <= 2.8` это баг или ограничение на сумму?

Answer (score 1):

```
"сумма ряда: {0}".format(z)
```

так использовать string format.
[Ответ на похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592133/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
In [149]: x = float(input('Введите X в интервале [1; 2.8]: '))
Введите X в интервале [1; 2.8]: 2.5

In [150]: z = sum(x/(n/10.+3*(n/10.)**2+5) for n in range(10, 29, 2))

In [151]: print(f"сумма ряда: {z:.8f}")
сумма ряда: 1.56287322
```

`range(start, stop, step)` - генерирует последовательные целые числа начиная со `start` и заканчивая `stop - 1` (включительно) с шагом `step`:

```
In [109]: list(range(10, 29, 2))
Out[109]: [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28]
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, что такое
range(10, 29, 2)

Comment: @mitajnn, добавил в ответ...

Answer (score 1):

Фраза "сумма ряда" может намекать, что `n=0..+inf`. Этот [ряд сходится (`x` вынесли за знак суммы, так как не зависит от `n`)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(n%2B+3n%5E2%2B5)+,n%3D0...%2Binf):

```
>>> import sympy  # $ pip install sympy 
>>> sympy.init_session()
# ...
>>> Sum(1/(3*n**2 + n + 5), (n, 0, oo))
  ∞               
 ____             
 ╲                
  ╲        1      
   ╲  ────────────
   ╱     2        
  ╱   3⋅n  + n + 5
 ╱                
 ‾‾‾‾             
n = 0             
>>> Sum(1/(3*n**2 + n + 5), (n, 0, oo)).evalf()
0.479338117368185
```

Чтобы напечатать таблицу значений c точностью `1e-8` для x на отрезке `[1, 2.8]` с шагом `0.2`:

```
>>> import numpy as np  # $ pip install numpy
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=8)
>>> x = np.arange(1, 3, .2)
>>> x
array([ 1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8])
>>> 0.479338117368185 * x
array([ 0.47933812,  0.57520574,  0.67107336,  0.76694099,  0.86280861,
        0.95867623,  1.05454386,  1.15041148,  1.24627911,  1.34214673])
```

Без `numpy`:

```
>>> print(*['%.8f' % (0.0479338117368185 * x10) for x10 in range(10, 30, 2)])
0.47933812 0.57520574 0.67107336 0.76694099 0.86280861
0.95867623 1.05454386 1.15041148 1.24627911 1.34214673
```

---

Сумму ряда [можно выразить](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(n%2B+3n%5E2%2B5)+,n%3D0...%2Binf) через [Гармоническое число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE):

```
>>> sumh = 1/sqrt(59)*I*(harmonic((-I/6)*(-5*I+sqrt(59))) - harmonic(I/6*(5*I+sqrt(59))))
>>> sumh
      ⎛          ⎛ⅈ⋅(√59 + 5⋅ⅈ)⎞           ⎛-ⅈ⋅(√59 - 5⋅ⅈ) ⎞⎞
√59⋅ⅈ⋅⎜- harmonic⎜─────────────⎟ + harmonic⎜───────────────⎟⎟
      ⎝          ⎝      6      ⎠           ⎝       6       ⎠⎠
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                              59                             
>>> re(sumh).evalf()
0.479338117368185
```

---

Для прямого вычисления с относительной точностью `1e-8` не обязательно до бесконечности пытаться суммировать, достаточно первые `n` слагаемых учесть:

```
>>>> import itertools
>>>> def find_n(isclose):
....     s = 0
....     for n in itertools.count():
....         s += 1.0 / (3*n*n + n + 5)
....         if isclose(s):
....             return n
>>>> sum1 = 0.479338117368185
>>>> find_n(lambda s: abs(s - sum1) / sum1 < 1e-8)
70112439
```

Тогда сумму можно найти приближённо прямым суммированием:

```
>>>> def sum_series(nlimit):
....     return sum(1.0 / (3*n*n + n + 5) for n in range(nlimit))
>>>> sum_series(70112440)
0.47933811257480385
```

Хотя округлённые результаты с вычисленной частичной суммой отличаются от результатов с точной суммой:

```
>>> 0.47933811257480385 * x
array([ 0.47933811,  0.57520574,  0.67107336,  0.76694098,  0.8628086 ,
        0.95867623,  1.05454385,  1.15041147,  1.24627909,  1.34214672])
```

разница меньше указанной точности:

```
>>> np.isclose(0.4793_3811_257480385 * x,
...            0.4793_3811_7368185   * x, 1e-8).all()
True
```